# if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, does that automatically imply that 4 does not divide $\phi(p^k)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

Problem:

> Describe all $m$ such that $\phi(m)$ is not divisible by $4$.

The solution for this is this set:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, then
>   $$T = \{p^k\text{ where }p \equiv 3\pmod 4\} \cup\{1, 2, 3\} \cup \{2m\mid m\in T\}$$

My main question is this:

We know that for $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4 $, $\phi(p)$ does not divide 4, because $\phi(p)$ is $p-1$.
But why does 4 also not divide $\phi(p^k)$, when p is congruent to 3 mod 4?

Comment: If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $p$ is odd, so $p^{k}$ is always odd as well.

Comment: Do you mean $4$ does not divide $p^k$? Only $1$, $2$, and $4$ divide $4$.

Comment: oops, so sorry, this question was not well-formed at all. I fixed it, thank you

Comment: is $p$ assumed to be a prime?

Comment: yes, will edit it!

Comment: I tried to make sense of your use of plain text when re-formatting your question, but the definition of $T$ is circular. I'm guessing you mean to take $T_0$ to be the first two parts and then take $T_0\cup 2T_0$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is prime, then
$$
\varphi\left(p^k\right)=(p-1)\,p^{k-1}
$$
so $4\mid\varphi\left(p^k\right)\iff p=2\text{ and }k\ge3\text{ or }p\equiv1\pmod{4}\text{ and }k\ge1$

Comment: so for $p$ an  odd prime, $\phi(p^k)$ is always even, and for a general $m$ : $\phi(m) = \prod_{p^k | m} \phi(p^k)$ so for $4 | \phi(m)$ it is enough that $m$ is divisible by two different odd primes, or ...

Comment: Yes. If it is divisible by a prime $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$ or any two distinct odd primes, then $4\mid\varphi(n)$.

Comment: but by that, this set is incorrect, right? {$p^k$ where $p≡3(mod4)$}